# Prevent XML empty tag parsing to zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, xml-parsing, sqlxml

I have an XML parameter with empty tag like this.

```
<dietTypes><dietType><dietaryID></dietaryID></dietType></dietTypes>
```

I am trying to parse it to an integer like this in a stored procedure,

```
DECLARE @MemDietTypes TABLE(DietaryID INT);
INSERT INTO @MemDietTypes
SELECT  DietTypes.Col.value('dietaryID[1]', 'INT')
FROM   @DietaryTypeXML.nodes('//dietType') DietTypes(Col);
```

The above is parsed as zero, which is problematic for me. How can I prevent this happening? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to return blank in DietaryID ?

Comment: @Nitika, yes I do.

Answer (score 2):

Try this to understand the implicit defaults:

```
SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT)
      ,CAST('' AS INT)
      ,CAST('      ' AS INT);
```

A `NULL` remains unchanged, but *empty* is defaulted to a zero. That is the designed behaviour.

Now back to your issue:

```
DECLARE @DietaryTypeXML XML='<dietTypes>
                               <dietType>
                                 <dietaryID></dietaryID> <!-- This is empty -->
                               </dietType>
                             </dietTypes>';
```

--The engine gets an empty value and defaults it to a zero.
--If you use `varchar` instead, you get a blank, but you'll have to deal with string-typed numbers.

```
SELECT  DietTypes.Col.value('dietaryID[1]', 'INT') AS Empty_in_INT_is_implicitly_taken_as_zero
       ,DietTypes.Col.value('dietaryID[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Empty_in_VARCHAR_is_implicitly_taken_as_empty_string
FROM   @DietaryTypeXML.nodes('//dietType') DietTypes(Col);
```

--The solution I suggest:

```
SELECT  DietTypes.Col.value('dietaryID[1] cast as xs:int?', 'INT') 
FROM   @DietaryTypeXML.nodes('//dietType') DietTypes(Col);
```

Using the XQuery `cast as xs:int?` tells the engine, that the given value is a nullable int. Now the value returned is no more *empty* but *NULL*.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `text()` function:

```
declare @data xml = '
    <dietTypes><dietType><dietaryID></dietaryID></dietType><dietType><dietaryID>2</dietaryID></dietType></dietTypes>';

select
    t.c.value('(dietaryID/text())[1]', 'int')
from @data.nodes('//dietType') as t(c);
```

returns:

```
dietaryID
-----------
NULL
2
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]You need to change datatype of DietaryID to varchar()

```
declare @xml xml='<dietTypes>
<dietType>
<dietaryID></dietaryID>
</dietType>
</dietTypes>'

DECLARE @MemDietTypes TABLE(DietaryID varchar(10));
INSERT INTO @MemDietTypes
SELECT  DietTypes.Col.value('dietaryID[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)')
FROM   @xml.nodes('//dietTypes/dietType') DietTypes(Col);

select * from @MemDietTypes
```

Comment: I am afraid, It still returns zero. :(

Comment: I am using MS-SQL. And  I am getting blank as output.

Comment: I am using MSSQL, I am getting zero

Comment: @Nikita, although this might work, it is not the best approach. You will have to deal with string-typed values and the risk of implicit conversion errors... You might look into my answer to find a way how to use XQuery casting to solve this in a *type-safe* way.